# Crop the image using Jquery in C# and ASP.Net

Tags: image, jquery-ui

I am having a image in one page and i have to crop the image to the predefined borders to crop this should happen using jquery and it has to be done in C# and ASP.Net and this is done by using Client side not the server side.
but the X and Y coordinate values must be saved in hidden fields and used for backend

plz reply me ASAP it is very urgent

ThanQ,
Vara Prasad.M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a jQuery plugin to make the crop region and find the co-ordintes for cropping, and then pass these values to the C# code and crop the image.

See **[Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)** for a jquery crop plugin and

**[How to crop an image using C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)**