# Extract sub image from an Image using c#

Tags: c#, image

I have a Bitmap object from this I need to extract a sub image and keep it as a Bitmap object by passing Rectangle object which contains sub image co-ordinates?

Is there a c# library which is able to do this or is Aforge able to extract sub image.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Bitmap class has a [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) method which accepts a target rectangle directly.

Since you're already working with a `Bitmap`, calling `Clone` with your rectangle and desired `PixelFormat` (which could be `originalBitmap.PixelFormat`) should give you what you need, with no additional dependencies.

```
Bitmap croppedImage = originalBitmap.Clone(theRect, originalBitmap.PixelFormat);
```

Comment: how to do it not using a rectangle? I need a trapezoid shape copy

Comment: If PixelFormat is not indexed color, then Clone operation will throw an Out of Memory error.