# how to crop an image

Tags: c#, jquery, crop, jcrop

I am using Jcrop to try crop and image and save it.

```
http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html
```

Out of the demos this is the one i am implementing:

```
http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler
```

It gives me several coordinates x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y

once these are submited how do i use them to crop the image?

I have looked at http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

is this the best way? and it is only using x, y, w and h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktyfbs10.aspx) is a better idea to crop the image in c#

```
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(...);
Bitmap src = Image.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap;
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

 using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
 {
  g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), 
                cropRect,                        
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
 }
```

From the source [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

Comment: whats in new rectangle?? not sure how this is suppose to work

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi  excuse me answer you are providing already in stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c by "Daniel LeCheminant" at least mentioning his name will be Good.

Comment: @MMK:- I am really sorry for that. I have just updated my answerr with the source thread. Hope that is ok? And thanx for updating me!!

Comment: :) at last credit should be given to person who has answered already.

Comment: @MMK:- rightly said!!! but it can be given to the person who has dig it out from the well!!! ;)

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi i remember because i used his solution for one of my tasks, an upvote for Daniel LeCheminant

Comment: @MMK:- Not a problem Sir!! My effort was to help to OP's question. If I dont get an upvote from you...thats alright!!