# How to print bitmap without zoom from MVC controller in Debian

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bitmap, mono, system.drawing, wkhtmltoimage

Document is printed from MVC controller to Debian Squeeze Linux server printer using code below in Mono.

Page in printer is A4.

Printed text in paper is too big and unsharp. Rightmost part of text is not visible since it does not fit to page.

If printed from Windows from .NET to HP Laserjet, output is correct.

So it looks like Mono  or Samsung ML-331x Series printer zooms bitmap for unknown reason which causes too big and unsharp output.

How to fix this so that bitmap is printed like in windows ?

Possible solutions:

1. Best way would be to print formatted html directly. How to do it in server where there are no browser installed? wkhtmltopdf does not support printing. I posted it in [How to print formatted html in Linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717210/how-to-print-formatted-html-in-linux-server)
2. Maybe it is possible to use wkhtmltopdf convert html to pdf instead of bitmap I posted it as separate question in [How to print pdf in debian linux from MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712356/how-to-print-pdf-in-debian-linux-from-mvc-controller)
3. wkhtmltoimage can produce also other image formats. Maybe some other format is better ?
4. Maybe some wkhtmltoimage command line swithches like `--width=750` or `--dpi` can fix this ?

```
public class Test: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Print()
    {
        PrintOrderVormiga();
        return new ContentResult() { Content = "OK" };
    }

    void PrintOrderVormiga()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Insert(0, " test ", 500);
        var bmp = ConvertHtmlToBMP("<html><body>" +sb.Tostring()+ "</body></html>");
        var doc = new PrintDocument();
        doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Samsung ML-331x Series";
        doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
        pageHeight = doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height;
        using (bm = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(bmp)))
        {
            lehti = (int)Math.Ceiling(bm.Height / (double)pageHeight);
            doc.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
            doc.PrinterSettings.ToPage = lehti;
            pageno = 0;
            doc.Print();
        }
    }

    int pageno, lehti;
    int pageHeight;
    Bitmap bm;

    void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(0, pageHeight * pageno++,
            bm.Width, pageHeight);
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                       cropRect,
                       GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        e.HasMorePages = pageno < lehti;
    }

    static byte[] ConvertHtmlToBMP(string html)
    {
        string programm = "wkhtmltoimage";
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT)
        {
            programm = "wkhtmltoimage-amd64";
        }

        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT ?
                "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\" + programm + ".exe" : "/usr/bin/" + programm
            }
        };

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "--format bmp --disable-javascript --quality 10";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments += " - -";
        p.Start();
        using (var stream = p.StandardInput)
        {
            byte[] ibuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
            stream.BaseStream.Write(ibuffer, 0, ibuffer.Length);
            stream.WriteLine();
        }

        var buffer = new byte[32768];
        byte[] file;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            file = ms.ToArray();
        }

        p.WaitForExit(60000);
        var returnCode = p.ExitCode;
        p.Close();
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW: the above is not [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, if your question involves a comparison between behavior on Windows vs behavior on Linux, you need to provide the good code example for Windows too. The most likely explanation for your problem is that you are simply rendering the bitmap at a higher resolution in Windows than in Linux, but without good code examples, it's not really possible to say for sure.

Comment: This is complete MVC controller class which can invoked from browser in  MVC application. It can probably refactored for console application. Exactly same code runs in both windows and Linux (there are two `Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT` checks in code) but in Linux result document is zoomed and characters in document are unsharp. How to force bitmap print without zoom and text smoothing in Linux ?

Comment: @PeterDuniho . Maybe the best way is to print formatted html directly. I updated this question and posted this as separate question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717210/how-to-print-formatted-html-in-linux-server

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [HTML to PDF Converter for Mono](https://html-to-pdf.com/2016/07/07/html-to-pdf-for-mono/) solution from EvoPdf. The C# code for converting a HTML to PDF in Mono is:

```
        // create the HTML to PDF converter object
        HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter(serverIPAddress, serverPortNumber);

        // set service password if necessary
        if (serverPassword.Length > 0)
            htmlToPdfConverter.ServicePassword = serverPassword;

        // set PDF page size
        htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;

        // set PDF page orientation
        htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;

        // convert the HTML page from given URL to PDF in a buffer
        byte[] pdfBytes = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(urlToConvert);
```