# How to print formatted html in Linux server

Tags: linux, mono, wkhtmltopdf, printdocument, printing-web-page

ASP.NET MVC 4 application runs in Debian Squeeze Linux using Mono.

Controller creates html document like code below.
html contains simple positioning divs and formatting instructions.

Linux server is running in internet provider and there are no desktop components installed. Additional components can installed if required. This is older, squeze x64 linux.

How to print this html file to Samsung printer connected to server ?

It there some executable which can used for this ? wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage do not have print options.

```
       public class Test: Controller {
        public ActionResult Print()
        {
            PrintOrderVormiga();
            return new ContentResult() { Content = "OK" };
        }

        void PrintOrderVormiga()
        {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Insert(0, " <b>test</b> ", 500);
            var doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Samsung ML-331x Series";
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
            doc.Print();
        }

        StringBuilder sb;

        void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
          ?? how to print sb.ToString() as formatted html ?
        }
  }
```

Comment: You can just use `lpr -d print device pdffiletoprint`. If you have html, convert it to either a pdf or postscript and forward that to `lpr`

Comment: lpr man page describes that -P switch should used. Is `-d` really correct switch for printer name  ?

Comment: Sorry, that option `-d` is for `lp` , `lpr` does use `-P`...i.e. `lpstat -p -d` to get the device name and then `lp` or `lpr`. You can always set the printer as the default, `lpoptions -d printdevice`

Comment: Which is better to use, lp or lpr ?

Comment: personal preference mainly, lp allows the use of option files, etc... but the end result is the same.