# How to print pdf in debian linux from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net, pdf, printing, mono, wkhtmltopdf

AsP.NET MVC 4 application runs in Debian Squeeze Linux using Mono.
Controller creates pdf file from html using code below.

How to print pdf file to Samsung printer connected to server ?
It there some executable which can used for this ?

```
       public class Test: Controller {
        public ActionResult Print()
        {
            PrintOrderVormiga();
            return new ContentResult() { Content = "OK" };
        }

        void PrintOrderVormiga()
        {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Insert(0, " test ", 500);
            pdf = ConvertHtmlToPDF("<html><body>" +sb.Tostring()+ "</body></html>");
            var doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Samsung ML-331x Series";
            doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
            pageHeight = doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height;
            doc.Print();
        }

        byte [] pdf;

        void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
          ?? of to print this.pdf contents as pdf ?
        }


        static byte[] ConvertHtmlToPDF(string html)
        {
            string programm = "wkhtmltopdf";
            var p = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    FileName = Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT ?
                @"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\" + programm + ".exe" : "/usr/bin/" + programm
                }
            };

            p.StartInfo.Arguments += " - -";
            p.Start();
            using (var stream = p.StandardInput)
            {
                byte[] ibuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
                stream.BaseStream.Write(ibuffer, 0, ibuffer.Length);
                stream.WriteLine();
            }

            var buffer = new byte[32768];
            byte[] file;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                file = ms.ToArray();
            }
            p.WaitForExit(60000);
            var returnCode = p.ExitCode;
            p.Close();
            return file;
        }

  }
```

Comment: Could you call lp with [Process.Start](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2283716/3585500)?

Comment: Probably yes. I have no experience in Linux printing, how to call it to print pdf? In my knowledge, lp does not support pdf print, how it can used ? Maybe there is some application which can used to print pdf files in linux server ?

Comment: Looking around I saw several mentions of using [lpr to print a pdf file directly to a printer](http://askubuntu.com/a/170301). I'm AIX more than linux, so I don't know if it Just Works or if you have to install something.

Comment: Thank you. This is great idea. Is there sample command line for this ? Before trying this, is there a way to print formatted html directly, without conversion in server where there are no borwsers installed ? I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717210/how-to-print-formatted-html-in-linux-server