# Cut jpg iTextSharp.text.Image From top

Tags: c#, itext

I need to cut a .jpg image from top of 20 pixels.

I have this code to associate the image to the object:

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = pdf.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions("BarCode")[0].position;
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Application.StartupPath + segnacollo.BarCode);
img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(rect.Height);
img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(rect.Width);
img.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left, rect.Bottom);
pdf.GetOverContent(1).AddImage(img);
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the project's budget? Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to make a JPEG from a PDF? Or are you adding an existing JPEG to a PDF and you wish to cut off those pixels? Or is there a PDF that has an image inside of it and you want to cut some of those pixels off the top?

Comment: I am adding an existing JPG to a PDF and i need to cut off this pixels

Comment: @Ale Why don't you clip the image?

Comment: How can i clip a JPG image of 20 pixels?

Comment: I'd personally ignore iText for this and just [crop the image in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c) before adding it.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the answer to the question [How to give an image rounded corners?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-give-image-rounded-corners)

In this example, we clip an image so that it gets rounded corners:

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance(some_path_to_an_image);
float w = img.ScaledWidth;
float h = img.ScaledHeight;
PdfTemplate t = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(w, h);
t.Ellipse(0, 0, w, h);
t.Clip();
t.NewPath();
t.AddImage(img, w, 0, 0, h, 0, -600);
Image clipped = Image.GetInstance(t);
```

You want to remove part of the top of the image, you can make your code even simpler:

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance(some_path_to_an_image);
float w = img.ScaledWidth;
float h = img.ScaledHeight;
PdfTemplate t = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(w, h - 20);
t.AddImage(img, w, 0, 0, h, 0, 0);
Image clipped = Image.GetInstance(t);
```

In this example, I created a `PdfTemplate` that is 20 user units smaller than the original image. I add the original image to that template, and I create a new image from that template.

**Important:** this visually clips the image in the sense that you won't see the top strip (20 user units high) in the PDF. However, if you extract the image from the PDF, you'll see that the complete image is present in the document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry but i haven't understand how to save the file as JPG and what is writer in your code.

Comment: In the comments you say that you need a PDF, not a JPG. iTextSharp doesn't save JPGs, only PDFs.

Comment: I think this code example should state what type the `writer` object is.