# Crop an image starting from its center in C#

Tags: c#

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199315/2119562) answer, I made the following code for resizing an image while keeping the aspect ratio correct:

```
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int? width, int? height)
   {
       var dimensions = GetImageDimensions(image.Width, image.Height, width, height);

       var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, dimensions.Item1, dimensions.Item2);
       var destImage = new Bitmap(dimensions.Item1, dimensions.Item2);

       destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

       using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
       {
           graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
           graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
           graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
           graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
           graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

           using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
           {
               wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
               graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
           }
       }

       return destImage;
   }
```

I made the below method for getting the dimensions corrrect:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> GetImageDimensions(int originalWidth, int originalHeight, int? width, int? height)
    {
        double widthRatio = (double)originalHeight / (double)originalWidth;
        double heighthRatio = (double)originalWidth / (double)originalHeight;
        int newWidth = originalWidth;
        int newHeight = originalHeight;

        if (width.HasValue && !height.HasValue && width.Value <= originalWidth)
        {
            newWidth = width.Value;
            newHeight = (int)(width.Value * widthRatio);
        }
        else if (!width.HasValue && height.HasValue && height.Value <= originalHeight)
        {
            newHeight = height.Value;
            newWidth = (int)(height.Value * heighthRatio);
        }

        return new Tuple<int, int>(newWidth, newHeight);
    }
```

My problem: In case a user fills in both a new width *and* a new height, instead of resizing the image I want to crop it (starting from the center pixel of the original image). See this image:

[image]

If I have an image that was originally 1000x1000 pixels (red in the image), and I pass it to my method along with a new with and height (both 500), I want to return a cropped image (green in the image). However, no matter what parameter I change in the `ResizeImage` method, I can't seem to crop the image. In the call to `graphics.DrawImage`, I've tried changing all of the parameters, but I can't seem to get the result as described in the image above. What's going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize an Image C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop an image using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest a change to your `GetImageDimensions` method - it should also return whether to resize or to crop:

```
public static Tuple<int, int, bool> GetImageDimensions(int originalWidth, int originalHeight, int? width, int? height)
{
    double widthRatio = (double)originalHeight / (double)originalWidth;
    double heighthRatio = (double)originalWidth / (double)originalHeight;
    int newWidth = originalWidth;
    int newHeight = originalHeight;
    bool cropping = false;

    if (width.HasValue && !height.HasValue && width.Value <= originalWidth)
    {
        newWidth = width.Value;
        newHeight = (int)(width.Value * widthRatio);
    }
    else if (!width.HasValue && height.HasValue && height.Value <= originalHeight)
    {
        newHeight = height.Value;
        newWidth = (int)(height.Value * heighthRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        cropping = true;
    }

    return new Tuple<int, int>(newWidth, newHeight, cropping);
}
```

Now, basically what you need to crop the image the way you want is the new dimensions *and* the location. Assuming that your `GetImageDimensions` method returns the correct dimensions, you can calculate the location as follows:

```
var newDimensions = GetImageDimensions(...);

// We need to detect whether to resize or to crop
bool mustCrop = newDimensions.Item3;

// Initialize your SOURCE coordinates
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int w = image.Width;
int h = image.Height;

// Adjust if we want to crop
if (mustCrop)
{
    x = (image.Width - newDimensions.Item1) / 2;
    y = (image.Height - newDimensions.Item2) / 2;
    w = newDimensions.Item1;
    h = newDimensions.Item2;
}
```

Now you create a new bitmap for the destination image with the new dimensions. After that, you can draw into the new image *providing both the location and the new size* as the **source** coordinates:

```
graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

This should handle both scaling and cropping. So your `ResizeImage` method would look like this:

```
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int? width, int? height)
{
   var dimensions = GetImageDimensions(image.Width, image.Height, width, height);

   // We need to detect whether to resize or to crop
   bool mustCrop = newDimensions.Item3;

   // Initialize your SOURCE coordinates. By default, we copy
   // then entire image, resizing it
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
   int w = image.Width;
   int h = image.Height;

   // Adjust if we want to crop
   if (mustCrop)
   {
       x = (image.Width - newDimensions.Item1) / 2;
       y = (image.Height - newDimensions.Item2) / 2;
       w = newDimensions.Item1;
       h = newDimensions.Item2;
   }

   var destImage = new Bitmap(dimensions.Item1, dimensions.Item2);
   destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

   using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
   {
       graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
       graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
       graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
       graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
       graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

       using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
       {
           wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
           graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(0,0), new Rectangle(x, y, w, h), GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
       }
   }

   return destImage;
```

}

Please note: I have not tried this. You may to fine-tune things, but you get the picture...

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to get your code to work, because there's no overload for `graphics.DrawImage` like in your code.

Comment: Then use another one. It doesn't really matter. The destination location must be `(0,0)`, the destination dimensions must be `(newDimensions.Item1, newDimensions.Item2)` and the source rectangle needs to be specified the way I did. There are other overloads that allow you to do that.

Comment: Got it, thanks for taking the time to help me out with your detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Image** class of **System.Drawing.Image** namespace which return the image in expected radio.

For example :

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(path); // actual image
Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(150, 150, () => false, IntPtr.Zero); //cropped image with height 150 and width 150
```

Comment: Doesn't `GetThumbnailImage` return the whole image but resized? I want to get this kind of behaviour: https://www.drupal.org/files/images/imagefield_crop.jpg

Comment: for that kind of functionality please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c