# How To Set The Width And Height In Image C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, drawing

I Have An Image And I just Need To Crop That

- For Example My Image's Pixel Is (257,50)
- I Just Need (200,20) Of That Pic I Don't Need The Rest Of That Pic
  How Can I Do That?
- [image: List item]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c

Comment: Do you want to crop it or just show one part of it?

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz yes

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz yes and save it as new pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function from [How to crop/resize image](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/how-to-crop-resize-images-in-c)

```
private Bitmap CropImage(Image originalImage, Rectangle sourceRectangle,
                    Rectangle? destinationRectangle = null)
    {
        if (destinationRectangle == null)
        {
            destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, sourceRectangle.Size);
        }

        var croppedImage = new Bitmap(destinationRectangle.Value.Width,
            destinationRectangle.Value.Height);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(originalImage, destinationRectangle.Value,
                sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return croppedImage;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Button click to choose an image and test
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string imageFile = ofd.FileName;

            Image img = new Bitmap(imageFile);
            Rectangle source = new Rectangle(0, 0, 120, 20);
            Image cropped = CropImage(img, source);
            // Save cropped image here
            cropped.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(imageFile) + "\\croppped." + Path.GetExtension(imageFile));
        }
    }
```