# Extract text from image with particular height and width

Tags: c#, .net

In that image particular height weight text need to be extract text. For that i used modiDocument. codes re below:

```
public string ExtractTextFromImage(string filepath)
{
    try
    {
        Document modiDocument = new Document();
        modiDocument.Create(filepath);
        modiDocument.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH);
        MODI.Image modiImage = (modiDocument.Images[0] as MODI.Image);
        string extractedText = modiImage.Layout.Text;
        modiDocument.Close();
        return extractedText;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return filepath;
}
```

From above code i can get fill text from image. how to take particular height width text from image.

Comment: It's a little unclear from your question, do you want to extract the text from a specific part of the image?

Comment: yes i have some height and width value. In that image that height and width region text needs to extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from https://stackoverflow.com/a/734941/3966756

You can use [`Graphics.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktyfbs10.aspx) to draw a cropped image onto the graphics object from a bitmap.

```
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(...);
Bitmap src = Image.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap;
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
   g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), 
                    cropRect,                        
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

*Quote end*

Using this Code for cropping the image you can only load the part of the Image you want to extract the text from.

Since i don't know if **MODIDocuments** support loading from a bitmap instead of a file you may need to write a temporary file somwhereon your filesystem.

Comment: from that cropped image how to extract text

Comment: Save the Bitmap to file and then use the temporary saved file instead of the original bitmap with your code