# How to crop bitmap and get the lower 50% of the Image

Tags: c#, image-processing, crop

I have an Image which I want to crop. I already know that my required content is in the lower part of the image so how can I automatically crop it using Rectangle ?

I tried to use this Code (Below) to crop but it didn't help. I haven't used Rectangle much so please guide me.

```
private Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap img)
{
    int height= img.Height / 2;
    Rectangle CropArea = new Rectangle(100,height, 1400, 900);
    Bitmap bmpCrop = img.Clone(CropArea, img.PixelFormat);
    return bmpCrop;
}
```

the cropped image turned out fine but it's hardcoded. I need to make it dynamic so it gives same result for different images

Comment: Just use the sizes ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. You've demonstrated awareness of the fact that you can obtain the image size via `img.Width` and `img.Height`, so where is the problem?

Comment: @John the width and height might change according to the cropped image. how can I handle that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop an image using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

Comment: @TheGeneral please explain

Comment: What do you mean "handle it"? If you crop an image by half its height, what is the new height? It's half the height. What's it's width? It's the original width.

Comment: @John I'm still a bit confused. it would be great if you could share some code.

Comment: `var startX = 100; var startY = img.Height /2; var newWidth = img.Width - startX; var newHeight = img.Height - startY;`

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @John for your answer. this code will cut 50% of the image and give your it's lower half:

```
private Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap img)
{
    int height= img.Height / 2;
    int newWidth = img.Width -100;
    int newHeight = img.Height - height;
    Rectangle CropArea = new Rectangle(100,height,newWidth,newHeight);
    Bitmap bmpCrop = img.Clone(CropArea, img.PixelFormat);
    return bmpCrop;
}
```