# Possible to cut an image based on the shape of another image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In Windows Presentation Foundation, I can't seem to find a way of how to cut an image based on the shape of another image.

E.g. I'd like to display someone's photo in the shape of a heart.

There are answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c) which crop an image into a rectangle or [like this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/clipping-or-cropping-images-in-wpf/) which draw a radius to clip the image into a circle.

But is cropping really the only way?

**Can WPF overlay the image on top of a shape and have the image be cut based on the shape dimensions?**

The code that I have so far does the *inverse* of what I'm trying to do. What I have so far uses an `overlay` layer as a mask to cover the `image`:

```xml
<Image 
    Name="HeartOverlay"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Panel.ZIndex="2"
/>
<Canvas 
    Name="Canvas"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image 
        Name="Image"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        Panel.ZIndex="1"
    />
/>
```

```cs
HeartOverlay.Source = new Bitmap(@"C:\heart.png");
Image.Source = new Bitmap(@"C:\image.png");
```

The problem here is that `overlay` is merged together with the `image` and saving/printing the image also shows the overlay.

See image below as an example. Note the white borders, which are especially evident when viewing the image in something like the Mac Preview app. I'm looking to save/print the image without the white borders.

Appreciate any pointers!

[image: heart overlay with borders]

Comment: Are you looking for [WPF Opacity Mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/opacity-masks-overview)

Comment: Instead of using an OpacityMask, it would be a lot simpler to either clip an Image element by a heart-shaped PathGeometry in its [Clip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.clip?view=netframework-4.8) property, or - even simpler - to fill a Path element with such a geometry with an ImageBrush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply fill a Path with a heart-shaped Geometry with an ImageBrush:

```
<Path Width="100" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform"
      Data="M1,2 L0,1 A0.5,0.5 1 1 1 1,0 A0.5,0.5 1 1 1 2,1 Z">
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\image.png"/>
    </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

Comment: Clemens, Path + ImageBrush is exactly what I was looking for. The image shows cropped in a heart-shaped form without the need for an overlay. Thank you.