# Google Cloud Vision API - client.DetectText - How Can I Get Specific Image Location Data?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-vision

I am currently using the client.DetectText method to extract data from some images. The images themselves never change location with specific data and I would like to get data for a specific area of the image.

Should I just reference the location in the text return (the specific line break) and hope that that is always it or is there a way with this code:

```
Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(imagepath);
    ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
    IReadOnlyList<EntityAnnotation> response = client.DetectText(image);
    string test = string.Empty;
    foreach (EntityAnnotation annotation in response)
    {
        if (annotation.Description != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            test += Environment.NewLine + annotation.Description;
        }
    }
```

That I can add parameters to force a specific image location. Or maybe I guess I could crop the image before hand in code somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to change the ratio of the image before the detection is done you can use the [CropHintsParams](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.CropHintsParams.html) in the [image context](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageContext.html) to build an [AnnotateImageRequest](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.AnnotateImageRequest.html) instead of passing the image directly.
2. If you want to apply a bounding box before the detection I would suggest performing a handmade image crop, because currently I don't see any available option through the C# client library. Check [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c) Otherwise you can filter the results afterwards with the BoundingPoly field in the text annotation result.

I would take a look at the [REST reference](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageRequest) to understand how the request should be build.

You can also take a look at the [Try it!](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) page and check how the JSONs are built.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm super new to this stuff but it seems like I can't attach anything to a annotateimagerequest object regarding the productsearchparams. I am coding in c# and would like to limit the detection to a section of the image.

I don't understand the REST reference much.

Comment: Hi, sorry I understood it wrong the productsearch thing, it is not an option in this case. I would suggest making the crop manually