# How to crop bitmap and save with original clarity of image?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, image-editing

When I crop a bitmap from an image, the clarity of the cropped bitmap is reduced. How to bring the original clarity of the bitmap when cropping.

```
temp = temporary bitmap image, 
varas.ptval = orignal image.
```

This is the result:

[image]

my code:

```
Bitmap temp;

Bitmap croped;

Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

rectangle.Height = varas.Rect_H;

rectangle.Width = varas.Rect_W;

rectangle.X = varas.Rect_X;

rectangle.Y = varas.Rect_Y;

temp = varas.ptval;

croped = cropBitmap(temp, rectangle);

varas.RGBcrop = croped;

croped.Save(paths + "\\" + "SPR_" + ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I want such a result:

[image]

Comment: Can you post code of `cropBitmap` method?

Comment: Based on comments/answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738176/7034621) a lot depends on exact resolution/scaling factor you're going for.