# I don't know why the black screen is copied when I copy bmp

Tags: c#

It is a code that copies 200x200 images from the x and y positions of the originalBmp and copies them to the rectbmp

There is no problem with the image and the x and y values

but rectbmp is always black

```
        Bitmap originalBmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\park\\Downloads\\imsi\\textImage.bmp");

        
        int x = (int)P.X;
        int y = (int)P.Y;

        
        int rectWidth = 200;
        int rectHeight = 200;

        
        Bitmap rectBmp = new Bitmap(rectWidth, rectHeight);

        
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rectBmp);
        g.DrawImage(originalBmp,new Rectangle(x-100, y-100, rectWidth, rectHeight));

        
        pictureBox1.Image = originalBmp;
        rectBmp.Save("C:\\Users\\park\\Downloads\\imsi\\result.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: Maybe try [`g.Flush()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.flush?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-drawing-graphics-flush) after drawing

Comment: if you save g or throw it into a picturebox is it black?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/734941/7034621) disposes all the objects, perhaps indeed it's not flushed properly?

Comment: Wrong DrawImage() overload, the rectangle applies to rectBmp.  Use [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-drawing-graphics-drawimage(system-drawing-image-system-int32-system-int32-system-drawing-rectangle-system-drawing-graphicsunit))

Comment: It's not coloring it black, a blank image is always black anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DrawImage` should be used with correct params to properly copy the desired portion from the `originalBmp` to the `rectBmp`. You can try using `DrawImage` with the destination rectangle and the source rectangle to fix your issue.

```cs
using (Bitmap originalBmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\park\\Downloads\\imsi\\textImage.bmp"))
{
    int x = (int)P.X;
    int y = (int)P.Y;

    int rectWidth = 200;
    int rectHeight = 200;

    using (Bitmap rectBmp = new Bitmap(rectWidth, rectHeight))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rectBmp))
        {
            Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(x - 100, y - 100, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            g.DrawImage(originalBmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = originalBmp;
        rectBmp.Save("C:\\Users\\park\\Downloads\\imsi\\result.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
}
```

Define the source rectangle (`srcRect`) to be the portion of the `originalBmp` that we want to copy. The destination rectangle (`destRect`) is defined as the area of the `rectBmp` where the image will be drawn.

Then, we call the `DrawImage` with the `originalBmp`, `destRect`, `srcRect`, and `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` as your params.

Comment: `Bitmap` also needs to be disposed

Comment: forgot about that but you are correct, thank you!